# Changing button text in runtime using FindControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am new to `ASP.Net` and I need some help.
What I am trying to achive is simply changing the text displayed in a button when the button is clicked using `FindControl('IDButton')`.

Below is my Code:

```
((Button)Class.btn_parent.FindControl("TTTS")).Text = "TT";
```

This code is working on `Page_Load` but doesn't do anything in `ClickEvent`.

Comment: That is because once the page is loaded all code behind has been executed. The code is server-side but the page loads in the client browser. You need to do this in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Change Button Text using ASP.Net Button Click event and Set Parent Control.

For example :

`<a>` is parent control inside there is `<button>` which is child of `<a>`

Html :

```
<a id="Parent" runat="server">
   <asp:Button ID="btnTemp" runat="server" Text="Test" onclick="btnTemp_Click" />
</a>
```

Now on button click set parent control text that is of . So on click of button, anchor tag will removed replace with text "Parent" and inside button will removed.
Code :

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

//button click event
protected void btnTemp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // get button object
    Button btn = (Button)sender;

    //Set clicked button text
    btn.Text = "Clicked";         

   //If you want set parent control then
   //find parent control and set value
   ((HtmlAnchor) btn.Parent.FindControl("Parent")).InnerText = "Parent";

}
```

Comment: I tried this code and I know it working, what I'm asking is how can I do it with the code written in the question, also I don't want to javascript as I'm not very familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

After page is loaded like Ram Anugandula showed in his example with Page_Load event, it become not server problem, but users and server can't change client code without loading entire page again(refresh button or F5 must clicked by user), if you really want to change button text use jquery/javascript, otherwise save data in session or file and after user reloads page you set your text on page, while page is STILL LOADING.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this code in the Page_PreRender event

   Button ctrl =  this.FindControl("TTTS") as Button;
   
   ctrl.Text = "Sample.";